# Can I implement a pin number login after first use on a mobile web app with no database?

Tags: php, android, ios, html

I want to develop a mobile app that I ask a user for some info. Name, Phone, Email, etc and then use that info for the second part of the app which helps them connect with advisers.

I don't want them to have to enter that information every time they open the app so I thought a quick login would be nice. They enter a pin and then are taking to the second page with the information they provided upon the first use of the app.

The problem is, my company does not want to store their user information in a DB(I don't know why or if this is possible) my immediate thought was local storage with HTML5 or using PHP to create a small file that can be used to store user info and PIN and use that.

So, my question is simple. **CAN** you implement a pin number login for a mobile web app using only the application, i.e. the Local Storage of HTML5, or something to that effect that will be retained for the longevity of the app.

**Language:** AngualarJS and a little PHP support.

**Platform:** Ionic framework for cross platform conformity.

Comment: if you are not creating a DB then there is no option of storage because user is free to clear cache.

Comment: Yes- you can do this with HTML5 storage. If the user clears their cache they simply have to login again, which is typically expected. You'll want to encrypt their information and do this in a secure fashion. EDIT: By definition, the HTML5 storage engine is a database.

Comment: If the info isn't sensitive in anyway.. use local storage... the only thing that could happen is that someone else using that device can theoretically retrieve that info.. and only one person can have it stored per device..

Comment: In short, no - you can't do it with local storage alone, the server needs to know what the valid PINs are... without that there is no login, just some data you pass to the server and it goes *"gee, that's nice, what do you want me to do with this then?"*. You don't *need* to store that data in a database but it's by far the easiest way to avoid data corruption in a multi-user environment... of course, if you don't really care about validating the users...

Comment: Thank you everyone. Validation isn't of the utmost importance, just really a way to link a pin to the info provided. I think I will use the HTMLStorage options and store JSON objects that contain the info. That way I can display multiple user if need be and compare the pins in those objects to the ones entered.